# how to run shared object (.so) file in ColdFusion with Linux

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I am very new to ColdFusion with Linux environment. Can anyone help me how I can run the shared object file in my application? Earlier we had a Windows server where we were executing a ddl file with the help of an executable file by using `<cfexecute>`

Comment: You should still be able to use `<cfexecute>`. You will just need to change what it is executing. How would you run the file from the operating system? That will get you started on what needs to be executed with `<cfexecute>`.

Comment: I have added the shared object file to library folder and executed directly using <cfexecute>. There is no error as well as no required file operation performed. Earlier I thought it might be because of permission issue, given 777 permission also.

Comment: So did it work?

Comment: Unfortunately not working

Comment: What is it doing? Is it throwing an error? Check the log files. Can you run the command from the server outside of ColdFusion (from a command line)? If so, can you run the same command as the same user that ColdFusion is running under?

Comment: The shared object file using for generating a licence file. As I’m not getting any error, quite difficult to find out the cause. Yes, i ran the same script in command line also, it’s running without any error but no required result also. So I’m searching for different approach